# How to solve the problem of creating my model?

Tags: migrate

how do I fix this problem?
No migrations to apply.

first delete folder
migrations,after create Class Product,
and create the Data filed
then in Terminal pycharm,
Wrote python manage.py makemigrations,
then saw the message Create model Product,
but when I Wrote python manage.py migrate,
I saw No migrations to apply.
I repeated this operation several times but it did not work